# How to solve an optimization problem with max in objective function

Tags: optimization

For example. The problem I'm working on is

\begin{align}
U(x,y)=(\max\{x,y\}+2)^3+5
\end{align}

I had a problem where min was in the objective function before, so I would set $x$ and $y$ equal.  I'm sure that's not the same in this situation but not sure how to approach it.

Comment: Are you trying to maximize or minimize $U$? Are there any constraints?

Comment: I'm trying to maximize.  Can we assume it I constrained optimization.  Is there no simple rule to follow as in if it was min{x,y} then there is an optimal interior solution at x=y?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this problem is not well posed. Whether you are trying to maximize or minimize $U$ over $(x,y)$, the problem is unbounded (to positive or negative infinity, respectively).